# Non-problematic XML-to-Java binding

Tags: java, xml, data-binding

I've looked all over the place for a good way to bind XML elements to Java classes. It sounds like a fairly easy thing to implement (for some value of easy), but wherever I look, there's the need for XSDs, explicit mapping and a bunch of other things that really get in the way for me.

This is my (possibly incomplete) idea of a Java object representing a sitemap.

```
public class Sitemap {

    private List<Url> urls;

    public List<Url> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setUrls(List<Url> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something which lets me do:

```
Sitemap sitemap = (Sitemap) Foo.fromXml("sitemap.xml")
```

Something like that, or at least similar. Is there any such thing?

Comment: Checkout:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: You can give JAXB a try also: http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5/docs/ch03.html

Comment: @ChadNC - MOXy is a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.  I've added an answer that demonstrates how JAXB can be used for this use case:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10854631/383861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is how this could be done with a JAXB ([**JSR-222**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)).  An implementation is included in Java SE 6.  There are also other implementations such as [**EclipseLink MOXy**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/MOXy) (I'm the tech lead).

**SHORT ANSWER**

You couls use the following API call with JAXB with any annotations or XML schemas.

```
Sitemap sitemap = JAXB.unmarshal(xml, Sitemap.class);
```

**LONG ANSWER**

Below is a more detailed example.

**Sitemap**

I've modified your class slightly.  I wasn't sure what the `Url` class was so I changed it to `java.net.URL`.  Note how no annotations are required on the domain model.

```
package forum10854001;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class Sitemap {

    private List<URL> urls;

    public List<URL> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setUrls(List<URL> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

Instead of the code used in the short answer, I have created a `JAXBContext`.  The JAXBContext is a thread safe object that represents all the initialized metadata.  The `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller` objects provider additional flexibility over the `JAXB` class.

The code below demonstrates how to read in the XML and them write it back out:

```
package forum10854001;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Sitemap.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum10854001/input.xml");
        JAXBElement<Sitemap> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Sitemap.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);

    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemap>
    <urls>http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php</urls>
    <urls>http://jaxb.java.net</urls>
</sitemap>
```

**For More Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! I'm going to have to have a look at MOXy, looks like something I might find very useful.

Comment: Blaise - I've used XStream a lot in the past (see my answer), but I'm glad see and learn of similar "simpler" approaches like MOXy.  What would you say are the advantages of JSR-222/MOXy over XStream?

Comment: @user949300 - Advantages of JAXB inlcude:  multiple implementations, impl included in Java SE 6, binding layer for JAX-WS & JAX-RS web services, can start from Java classes or XML schema (XStream FAQ recommends XMLBeans for the latter:  http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Uses).  Additional advantages with MOXy;  path based mapping (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html), external mapping document, support for JPA entities, etc.  XStream can do JSON binding, but so can MOXy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html.

Comment: So, I played with JAXB a bit.  I would say that one _slight_ advantage of XStream is that it still works, very simply, without forcing you to add annotations to fields of your objects.  With JAXB you either need to add annotations (which, in the long run for maintainability, is probably a good idea) or to go through an extra step with an introspector.  Right?

Comment: As per my example no annotations required.

Comment: Yes, but you aren't marshaling a Sitemap, you are marshaling a JAXBElement<Sitemap>.  When I try to directly marshal a Sitemap, I need the @XmlElement annotations.  (I'm using the built-in JAXB, not Moxy)

Comment: @user949300 - You are correct when the object is not annotated with `@XmlRootElement` you need wrap the object in an instance of `JAXBElement` To be fair though you need to take action with XStream as well since "com.your.name.here.Sitemap" isn't a great root element name.  Here is a comparison I wrote that you may find interesting:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).  Here is roughly equivalent code to Blaise's, though working in the opposite direction (starting with an Object, not XML) for variety:

```
public class Sitemap{
      private List<URL> urls = new ArrayList();

      // I left out the setters and getters

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Sitemap sitemap = new Sitemap();
         sitemap.urls.add(new URL("http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php"));
         sitemap.urls.add(new URL("http://jaxb.java.net"));

         XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver());
         String xmlString = xs.toXML(sitemap);
         System.out.println(xmlString);
         Sitemap readBack = (Sitemap) xs.fromXML(xmlString);
      }
   }
```

yields the following output:

```
<com.your.name.here.Sitemap>
  <urls>
    <url>http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php</url>
    <url>http://jaxb.java.net</url>
  </urls>
</com.your.name.here.Sitemap>
```

And you can set a breakpoint and view readBack in the debugger and it has both URLS.